# nullable date time exception

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, model-view-controller, nullable

On respository, I have nullable string `" o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate")"` converted to `nullable datetime`.

**Here is the code:**

```
PreorderLanchDate = o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate") == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate").Value),
```

On controller, launchdate is nullable, not getting the value, as it is showing the null value exception.
here is the code:

```
LaunchDate = (DateTime)product.PreorderLanchDate
```

Comment: Try LaunchDate =product.PreorderLanchDate as PreorderLanchDate is nullable

Comment: product.PreorderLaunchDate is a nullable 'DateTime' So you can try (DateTime?)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
  //along with the null reference check, Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate").Valuen
 PreorderLanchDate = o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate") == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate").Value) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(o.Attribute("PreorderLanchDate").Value), 



  //Cast to a nullable DateTime
LaunchDate = (DateTime?)product.PreorderLanchDate
```

Comment: LaunchDate = (DateTime?)product.PreorderLanchDate

LaunchDate is already initialised nullable in model class so its giving exception "cannot convert 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.Datetime'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast)"

Answer (score 1):

`product.PreorderLaunchDate` is a nullable `DateTime`, if it has the value of `null` you will get an exception casting it to a normal `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the as operator to perform certain types of conversions between compatible reference types or nullable types.

```
var nullableDateTime = product.PreorderLanchDate as DateTime;

if ( nullableDateTime != null )
    LaunchDate = nullableDateTime;
```